# unexpected behavior when extracting factor levels

Tags: r, levels

Can someone explain why levels() shows three factor levels, while you can see that the vector has only two?

```
> str(walk.df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ walker : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

> walk.df$walker
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
Levels: 1 2 3
```

I would like to extract a vector of levels, and I thought this was the proper way, but as you can see, a three sneaks in there which is messing up my function.

```
> as.numeric(levels(walk.df$walker))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: `...shows three variables` perhaps you meant `values` or `levels`?

Comment: You are right, I meant levels.

Comment: In retrospect, one can now use `droplevels()` on a subsetted object and avoid having this issue altogether.

Comment: In reply to retrospect, `[` method has `drop` argument. Oh, what do you know... @kohske already nailed it. RTFM @aL3xa, RTFM...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

probably walk.df is a subset of the factor variable with 3 levels.
say,

```
a<-factor(1:3)
b<-a[1:2]
```

then b has 3 levels.

A easy way to drop extra level is:

```
b<-a[1:2, drop=T]
```

or if you cannot access the original variable,

```
b<-factor(b)
```

Comment: You are correct, it is a subset. I've been mincing the object so hard that I forgot I'm sampling from the raw object - which has three levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign several factor levels to a factor that contains two levels:

```
 > set.seed(1234)
 > x <- round(runif(10, 1, 2))
 > x
  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
 > y <- factor(x)
 > levels(y)
 [1] "1" "2"
 > levels(y) <- c("1", "2", "3")
 > y
  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
 Levels: 1 2 3
```

or even no levels at all:

```
 > p <- NA
 > q <- factor(p)
 > levels(q)
 character(0)
 > levels(q) <- c("1", "2", "3")
 > q
 [1] <NA>
 Levels: 1 2 3
```

Comment: What I really wanted was extract the levels that appear in the subset. I have solved this with list.of.walkers <- sort(unique(walk.df$label)).